# How can I get the output of a Rscript command line script as an R object in the R console?

Tags: r, bash

I have a Rscript called `my.Script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
x <- rnorm(10)
x
```

which I can run from the bash command line.

Now I'd like to run this script from inside an R session and capture its output **as an R object**.

```
> x <- system('my.Rscript')
```

I imagine something like this inside the R console:

```
x <- readRDS(file=pipe(description = 'my.Rscript'))
```

and inside the script I'd put something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
x <- rnorm(10)
saveRDS(x=x, file = stdout())
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how this is possible?

Comment: Why you don't just use `source`?

Comment: `system('command', intern = T)` to internalize the result of a system command, or `capture.output()` to capture the output of an R function in your console, for example, `capture.output(summary(cars))`. Both of these avoid writing the result to a file.

Comment: I cannot use source because the script takes command line parameters via the `argparse` module. The point is that I get an R object back, not a character string representation of an R object. `capture.output(system('my.script', intern = T))` returns a character string.