# collect output of system rscript command as r object

Tags: r

I am using RStudio in Windows to develop and run a pipeline for multivariate analysis that involve big dataset (90 by ~ 60000 matrices). With matrices of such a size, I got "protection from stack overflow" pretty often. One way of avoid this problem, while still using RStudio as opposite to the regular Rgui, is to run my script(s) using the following syntax

```
system("Rscript --max-ppsize=500000, my_script.s").
```

However, running this command results in the script running succesfully, but I cannot get the desired output. If I run the previous command with the following option

```
opt-< system("Rscript --max-ppsize=500000, my_script.s", internal = TRUE)
```

I got the standard output to the terminal as output (as a character vector), but not the desired output.

Consider this toy examples:

save the following code in my_script.R

```
print("first call")
rnorm(15)
print("second call")
rnorm(20)
```

and run the following code from the console

```
a <- system("Rscript my_script.R", intern = TRUE)
a
```

As you can see, the output is a character vector of length 9 with the standard output to the console.

If you modify my_script.R as follow

```
print("first call")
i_want_this <- rnorm(20)
```

and then run it again

```
a <- system("Rscript my_script.R", intern = TRUE)
a
```

now the only thing stored in *a* is the output of the print command.

My question is: is there a way to collect the *i_want_this* variable as an r object (in this case a numeric vector of length 20) ?

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715211/how-can-i-get-the-output-of-a-rscript-command-line-script-as-an-r-object-in-the), without a satisfying answer.

Comment: Perhaps save the data you want as .rds or similar and later reload them?

Comment: Of course that would be a solution, but I am afraid of slowing thing down quite a lot with the writing-reading part. Moreover, my final aim is to run the pipeline in a parallel fashion (i.e. use foreach and doParallel) in order to treat several folds at the same time in a cross-validated procedure. I am not sure how to implement a writing-reading procedure in this context.